# Bootstrap carousel moves slightly up then down again when scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

my bootstrap carousel moves up a little then back down again every time the carousel scrolls. The red line indicates where the boxes move up to. Although the transition is very quick, it is still obvious. How would I fix this?

[image]

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-12">

        <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                        <ul class="thumbnails">
                            <li class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">&raquo; Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">&raquo; Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">&raquo; Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">&raquo; Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                  </div><!-- /Slide1 --> 
                <div class="item">
                        <ul class="thumbnails">
                            <li class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">&raquo; Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">&raquo; Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">&raquo; Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">&raquo; Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                  </div><!-- /Slide2 --> 
                <div class="item">
                        <ul class="thumbnails">
                            <li class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">&raquo; Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">&raquo; Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">&raquo; Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">&raquo; Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                  </div><!-- /Slide3 --> 
            </div>

            <div class="control-box">                            
                <a data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel" class="carousel-control left">‹</a>
                <a data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel" class="carousel-control right">›</a>
            </div><!-- /.control-box -->   

        </div><!-- /#myCarousel -->

    </div><!-- /.col -->          
    </div><!-- /.row --> 
    </div><!-- /.container -->



#myCarousel {
    position: center;
    padding: 2em;
}
/* Thumbnail Box */
.caption h4 {
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: left;
    }
        .btn.btn-mini {
            font-size: 18px;
            background-color: #00bcb3;
            color: #ffffff;
            }
/* Carousel Control */
.control-box {
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
    }
    .carousel-control{
        background: #000000;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 34px;
        font-weight: 600;
        line-height: 25px;
        opacity: 100;
        padding: 4px 10px 0px;
        position: static;
        height: 40px;
        width: 40px;
        }

// Carousel Auto-Cycle
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 8000
    })
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I used exactly the same code in my WordPress site. The point is that WordPress (or even my browser?) wraps comments like

```
<!-- /Slide1 -->
<!-- /Slide2 -->
```

with 
    <p> </p>.

That causes lowering of slide 2, 3 and so on (the first slide has no such comment in the beginning). Please inspect the source code of the page you retrieve in your browser and try getting rid of these paragraphs if present. Hope it will help.

Another specific for my case step was adding style to the class carousel-inner:

```
div.carousel-inner {
    height: 268px !important;
}
```

That's due to my items have a varying length of description, but I want to have navigation buttons on the same height disregarding the height difference.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving `max-height` it will restrict the carousel to move up and down. Do take note, Bootstrap has it own CSS but that might not sit well with your website. you might need to write your own css to ignore bootstrap CSS

Comment: Thanks but just tried max-height but the carousel still moves.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe due to your current style sheets. First, look at your main style sheet for `margin-top` or `margin-bottom` properties belong to `container-fluid` class. You will very likely find solution.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when the images you use are different sizes. Try to create a selector to the img and margin properties. You can try the following in you css:
    .carousel-inner a img{
     height:150px;
    margin:auto;
    }

Answer (score 0):

You might set padding or margin for ".carousel-inner", Try to avoid and use padding and margin for main ".carousel".

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the same `height` in img element.

```
.thumbnail img{
    height: 650px !important;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;

}
```